# MySQL select row with NOT LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql

This is how my table looks like:

```
SELECT table2.status, table1.title 
FROM table1 RIGHT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
```

```
status    title
EXPIRED   USER A
EXPIRED   USER B
ACTIVE    USER B
EXPIRED   USER C
```

And I want to get the titles from the users which status is not ACTIVE, I tried:

```
SELECT table2.status, table1.title 
FROM table1 RIGHT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id 
WHERE table2.status NOT LIKE 'ACTIVE'
```

```
status    title
EXPIRED   USER A
EXPIRED   USER B
EXPIRED   USER C
```

The problem is that User B has a status ACTIVE and EXPIRED and I want a table that
shows me everyone who has NO ACTIVE status in the table:

```
status    title
EXPIRED   USER A
EXPIRED   USER C
```

Comment: Just a side remark: It seems strange that you outer join table1, because an outer joined record would have NULL for a title. What information would you gain from such result records? It seems also strange that you join by table1.id = table2.id, but I guess that's just in your simplified example and not in your real database, right?

Comment: As to your question: What would you want to show, if a user had two entries, 'ACTIVE' plus some other status other than 'EXPIRED' ('CANCELLED' for instance). Would you want to show both entries or only one? If only one: as 'ACTIVE', 'CANCELLED' or 'VARIOUS'?

Comment: i did not think about that, but you are right in my database it is possible to have status like ACTIVE, EXPIRED, CANCELLED and NEW...now it shows me the title of an user a few times, but I want just the users that have no ACTIVE-status, but everything else is okay. do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: Okay, just answer the question I asked above and I think it will be easy to provide you with a solution :-)

Comment: Actually I just need one column with the title of the user, and this table should show every user just ONE time who has NO active status...I hope I answered your question

Comment: Aain: if a 'USER X' has two statusses: 'EXPIRED' and 'CANCELLED', you want one result record with name = 'USER X' and status = **WHICH???**

Comment: 'USER X' and status = EXPIRED

Comment: Well, it seems my question was too concrete :-( What if the statusses were 'NEW' and 'CANCELLED' or if they were 'NEW' and 'EXPIRED'. What to show then? What is the *rule*?

Comment: 'EXPIRED' if it is in the combination, otherwise 'CANCELLED', and then 'NEW'

Comment: Okay, I've posted an answer. As you see, it took a while to find out what you wanted. I hope next time you are going to be more specific in your request from the start, so as not to cause unnecessary work such as this time :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a statement that gives you one row per non-active user:

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN MAX( case when table2.status = 'EXPIRED' then 1 else 0 end ) = 1 THEN 'EXPIRED'
    WHEN MAX( case when table2.status = 'CANCELLED' then 1 else 0 end ) = 1 THEN 'CANCELLED'
    WHEN MAX( case when table2.status = 'NEW' then 1 else 0 end ) = 1 THEN 'NEW'
    ELSE 'NOT ACTIVE'
  END as status
  table1.title 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id 
GROUP BY table1.title
HAVING MAX( case when table2.status = 'ACTIVE' then 1 else 0 end ) = 0;
```

The trick is here to get all rows, group by user and kind of create a flag if there exists an ACTIVE status for the user. If so, remove the user from the list in the HAVING clause. Then we decide which status to show. Again we use aggregated flags to find out if our preferred flag 'EXPIRED' exists or 'CANCELLED' otherwise etc.

BTW: I removed the right outer join, because it doesn't make sense to me. If it really happens that there are users without an entry in table1, then outer join, but have table2.id in the result columns and group by this instead of by table1.title.

Answer (score 3):

It would help if you showed your table structure.  But here is one way to approach this:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from table2 t2
                  where t2.id = t1.id and
                        t2.status = 'ACTiVE'
                 );
```

Comment: To me this appears it will return the same as the OP's query, won't it?

Comment: @TomasPastircak . . . This should return rows from table1 that have no active record in table2.  The OP's query will return rows from table1 if there is a record in table2 that is not active.  These are not the same thing, as exemplified by the example in the question of an id with both an active and expired record.

Answer (score 0):

Select title where status is not active.

```
select * from table_name 
where title not in( select distinct title 
                    from table_name 
                    where status = 'ACTIVE' )
```

sub query fetches those titles whose status is `ACTIVE` and the
outer query fetches all records whose title is not in the `ACTIVE` status.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly use an extra outer join, like this:-

```
SELECT table2.status, table1.title 
FROM table2 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 
ON table1.id = table2.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 table2a
ON table1.id = table2a.id 
AND table2a.status LIKE 'ACTIVE'
WHERE table2.status NOT LIKE 'ACTIVE'
AND table2a.id IS NULL
```

Join back against table2 again but only for active records and then put a check in the WHERE clause that the joined row for active records is null (ie, not found)